# Knockout with SharePoint multiple lists

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, knockout.js, sharepoint-2010

Hi I'm new with Knockout and now I'm trying to include it in SharePoint.
In SharePoint I don't have any Database that's why I'm using Lists.
I have many list. One is default which contains name of the others.
For example: Brand, Car 01, Car 03 and Car 04. In Brand I have 2 column- "Title" and "Car Name"-Name of the list with Car. In Car I have many column like "Name", "Model", "Year of product" and etc.
I want to use Knockout to display everything with two foreach. First one will display Title of the Brand List and the other one will display everything which is related with Car list name.
The result will be:

> Brand Title- Car 01
>
> ```
>  car 01 name , car 01 model
>  car 02 name , car 02 model
>  car 03 name , car 03 model
> ```
>
> Brand Title - Car 02
>
> ```
>  car 01 name , car 01 model
>  car 02 name , car 02 model
>  car 03 name , car 03 model
> ```
>
> Brand Title - Car 04
>
> ```
>  car 01 name , car 01 model
>  car 02 name , car 02 model
>  car 03 name , car 03 model
> ```

What I have for now:

knockout.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
   <head>
      <script src="/SiteAssets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="/SiteAssets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/SiteAssets/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
      <script src="/SiteAssets/js/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/SiteAssets/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="taskContainer">
         <h3>CARS</h3>
         <div id="errorBox" data-bind="text: errorMessage, visible: errorMessage"></div>
         <div id="saveBox" data-bind="text: saveMessage, visible: saveMessage"></div>

         <div data-bind="foreach: listOfBrands">
            <div>Brand: <span data-bind="text: BrandName"></span></div>         
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>Car name</th>
                  <th>Model</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTaskBox" data-bind="foreach: carItems, visible: carItems().length > 0">
               You have <b data-bind="text: carItems.length">&nbsp;</b> incomplete task(s)
               <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: nameOfCar" ></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Model" ></td>

               </tr>
            </tbody >
         </table>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="/SiteAssets/js/knockout-extension.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

And this is my knockout-extension.js

> (function() {
>
> ```
> function Task(data) {
>     this.nameOfCar = ko.observable(data.Title);
>     this.Model = ko.observable(data.Model);
>
>     // An additional reference to store the SharePoint list item id.
>     this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
> }
>
> function listOfBrandss(data) {
>
>   this.BrandName = ko.observable(data.BrandName);
>     this.carName = ko.observable(data.carName); 
>     // An additional reference to store the SharePoint list item id.
>     this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
>     this.calendarItems = ko.observableArray();        }
>  
> function carViewModel() {
>     //START Data 
>     var self = this;
>     
>     //START List 
>     self.listOfBrands = ko.observableArray([]);
>     self.carName = ko.observable();
>     self.BrandName = ko.observable();
>     //END List 
>     
>     //START item 
>     self.cars = ko.observableArray([]);
>     
>     self.Name = ko.observable();
>     self.Model = ko.observable();
>
>   //END item 
>                   //END Data  
>   
>     // Additional bindings to use for error and saved messages.
>     self.saveMessage = ko.observable(false);
>     self.errorMessage = ko.observable(false);
>      
>     self.incompletecars = ko.computed(function() {
>         return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.cars(), function(task) { return !task._destroy});
>     });
>  
>     // Operations
>     self.addTask = function() {
>         self.cars.push(new Task({ Title: this.Name(), Model: this.Model(), Id: "New" }));
>         self.Name("");
>     };
>      
>     self.removeTask = function(task) {
>         self.cars.destroy(task)
>     };
>      
>      self.save = function() {
>
>         for (var task in self.cars()) {
>          
>             var createdcars = [];
>              
>             // Build a request up to send with the CSOM.
>          
>             if (self.cars()[task]._destroy) {
>                 // Handle deleted objects
>                 // Deleted items that are marked "new" have never been saved to SharePoint to start with,
>                 if (self.cars()[task].Id() != "New") {
>                     var listItem = taskList.getItemById(self.cars()[task].Id());
>                     listItem.deleteObject();
>                 }
>             } else if (self.cars()[task].Id() == "New") {
>                 // Handle new objects to be created.
>              
>                 var createInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
>                 var listItem = taskList.addItem(createInfo);
>                  
>                 listItem.set_item("Title", self.cars()[task].Title());
>                 listItem.set_item("Model", self.cars()[task].Model());
>                 
>                 listItem.update();
>                  
>                 // Save a reference to both the SP.ListItem object and the KO Object so we can update
>                 // the latter with the former's ID once the object has been created.
>                 createdcars.push({
>                     spItem: listItem,
>                     koItem: self.cars()[task]
>                 });
>                  
>                 ctx.load(listItem);
>             } else {
>                 // The item is neither new nor deleted, handle it as an update.
>                 var listItem = taskList.getItemById(self.cars()[task].Id());
>
>                 listItem.set_item("Title", self.cars()[task].Title());
>                 listItem.set_item("Model", self.cars()[task].Model());
>
>                  
>                 listItem.update();
>             }
>              
>         }
>         // Nowe we have built our request, send it to the server for processing.           
>         ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
>          
>             // Our save was successful. Now we need to itterate through our newly
>             // created items and ensure that Knockout knows that the ID has changed.
>             for(var item in createdcars) {
>                 createdcars[item].koItem.Id(createdcars[item].spItem.get_id());
>             }
>              
>             // Set our saved message.
>             self.saveMessage("Saved successfully");
>              
>         }, function(sender, args) {
>          
>             // Our save failed, set the error message to show then log the actual error
>             // to the JavaScript console if it exists.
>             self.errorMessage("Error updating list items");
>             if (typeof console != "undefined") {
>                 console.log(args.get_message());
>             }
>         });
>          
>     };
>      
>    /// Load the data from SharePoint
>     // Get a context to the current site.
>     var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
>      
>     var web = ctx.get_web();
>     var taskList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("NameOFLIST!!!");
>      
>     // Limit our task list to 50 cars.
>     var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
>     query.set_viewXml("<View><</View> ");
>      
>     var taskItems = taskList.getItems(query);
>      
>     // Ensure the fields we want to retrieve are returned
>     ctx.load(taskItems, "Include(ID,Title,Model)");
>      
>     // Send our query to the server for processing.
>     ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
>         var cars = [];
>         var taskItemEnumerator = taskItems.getEnumerator();
>          // Iterate through our retrieved data set and build an array of JSON objects containing
>         // the relevent properties.
>         while (taskItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
>             cars.push(
>                 new Task({
>                     Title: taskItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Title"),
>                     Model: taskItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Model"),
>                     Id: taskItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item("ID")
>                 })
>             );
>         }
>          
>         // Update the Knockout cars array with our data from the server.
>         self.cars(cars);
>     });
>     
>     
>     //START Get all
>     var loc = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
>      
>     var web = loc.get_web();
>     var locList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Brand");
>      
>     // Limit our task list to 50 cars.
>     var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
>     query.set_viewXml("<View><RowLimit>50</RowLimit></View> ");
>      
>     var locItems = locList.getItems(query);
>      
>     // Ensure the fields we want to retrieve are returned
>     loc.load(locItems , "Include(ID,Title,Car name)");
>     
>     // Send our query to the server for processing.
>     loc.executeQueryAsync(function() {
>         var locA = [];
>         var locItemEnumerator = locItems.getEnumerator();
>          // Iterate through our retrieved data set and build an array of JSON objects containing
>         // the relevent properties.
>         while (locItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
>             //locA.push(
>              var cos =  new listOfBrandss({
>                     BrandName: locItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Title"),
>                     carName: locItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Car_x0020_name"),
>                     Id: locItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item("ID")
>                 });
>             //);
>           /*HERE IS PLACE FOR CODE*/
>             locA.push(cos);
>         }
>          
>         // Update the Knockout cars array with our data from the server.
>         self.listOfBrands(locA);
>     });       //END Get all Calendar from "List of Calendars"
>     
>      
> }
>
>
> $(document).ready(function() { // I use jQuery for this, but you could add an event listener to the document object instead.
>     EnsureScriptFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() {
>         ko.applyBindings(new carViewModel());
>     });
> });   })();
> ```

As much as I know I must to put the code there where I have "HERE IS PLACE FOR CODE" and I must to call 'Load the data from SharePoint" Everything what i tried is without success :(

Comment: In your code you have `query.set_viewXml("<View><</View> ")` with two '<<'. I don't know if it's the reason but maybe you can check that. Also use Firefox + Firebug to look at the requests sent to the server and the answers received. It's a very good way to know if something is wrong with the data. And, finally you may want to use SharepointPlus (http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) or SPServices to simply your interaction with Sharepoint Lists: the native Microsoft API is hard to use and not really clear.

Comment: "the native Microsoft API is hard to use and not really clear" that's debatable, but nice shameless plug for your project....

Comment: You might be better off asking this over at SP-SE: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: I agree the MS api leaves room for improvement. I think that in your INCLUDE statement, it should be Car_x0020_Name.  I have just scraped my nails on this chalkboard and the _x0020_ seems to be needed both there and in get_current().get_item('car_x0020_name')  If Im wrong in this specific case, it was needed in my case...